# My Sidebar is getting behind the content and webpage is losing responsiveness

Tags: flexbox, responsiveness

I'm a newbie.So, I tried putting CSS cards on a page that has a sidebar. I used Html & CSS flexbox. First I made them separately and they were perfectly fine and responsive. When I tried merging the both in a single page, the cards came in front of the navbar and the page overall loses its responsiveness too, as the cards lose their form. So, how can I fix this issue?

```css
:root{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    --text-primary: #b6b6b6;
    --text-secondary: #ececec;
    --bg-primary: #152238;
    --bg-secondary: #141418;
    --transition-speed: 600ms;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #bbff99;
    background-image: linear-gradient(319deg, #bbff99 0%, #ffec99 37%, #ff9999 100%);
    background-size: cover;

}

/* Used to colorize the browser scrollbar*/
body::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0.45rem;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: #1e1e24;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #6649b8;
}

main{
    margin-left: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.todima{
    position: relative;
    top: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
}


.navbar{
    width: 4.5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
    transition: width 200ms ease;
}

.navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}


.logo{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.3ch;

}

.navbar-item{
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-item:last-child{
    margin-top: auto;
}

.nav-link{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 5rem;
    color: var(--text-primary);
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
    transition: var(--transition-speed);

}
.nav-link:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0%) opacity(1);
    background: #0a304a;
    
}

.link-text{
    display: none;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.nav-link i{
    min-width: 2rem;
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
.navbar:hover{
    width: 16rem;
}
.navbar:hover .link-text{
    display: block;
}

.fas{
    color: #F98125;
    transition:var(--transition-speed);
}
.a1{
    font-family: 'Major Mono Display', monospace;
}


h1{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    margin: 7px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-size: 36px;
    color:#0B1354;
}

p{
    margin: 7px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    color: #660F56;
}


.cardcont{
    background: #FFFAFA;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 40px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    perspective: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
}

.cardcont:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.cardcont:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cardcont:hover{
    border-width: 8px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-left-color: #e975a8;
    border-top-color:#e975a8 ;
    border-bottom-color: #7ddff8;
    border-right-color: #7ddff8;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


.container{
    position: relative;
    top: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card-image{
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin: 6px;
}
.image-1{
    background-image: url(dashboardprofile.png);
}

.image-2{
    background-image: url(picks.png);
}

.image-3{
    background-image: url(http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/_uploads/photos/b5f9c7fc/pexels-suzy-hazelwood-1130980_450x130.jpg);
}

.image-4{
    background-image: url(contributor.png);
}

.image-5{
    background-image: url(request.png);
}

.image-6{
    background-image: url(logout.png);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard withh Cards</title>
    <!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7d904839de.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mergerdraft.css">  
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@600&family=Major+Mono+Display&family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="logo">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <span class="link-text logo-text">Cuet Course Insights</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-file-download fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Download books</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Report an issue</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Log Out</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <section class="todima">
            <h1 class="a1">Welcome to your dashboard</h1>
            <p>Glad to have you here. Hope you make the best use of your time. </p>
        </section>
        <section class="container">
            <a href="dashboard.html" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-1"></div>
                <h1>Profile</h1>
                <p>Visit your profile and all related information in this tab</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-2"></div>
                <h1>Your Picks</h1>
                <p>See your specially hand-picked items, without the peril of following all the steps.</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-3"></div>
                <h1>Course materials</h1>
                <p>Find and read the Books, Previous year Questions, Notes of all the toppers from our vast library of resources. In short, GO FOR GLORY!</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-4"></div>
                <h1>Be a Contributor</h1>
                <p>Wanna contribute to the community? No one ever regrets it, by helping others who might be in need. Go on!</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-5"></div>
                <h1>Request materials</h1>
                <p>Click here to reach us. Request content(question papers, books) for any course of any department and we'll hear you out. Just fill up the details.</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-6"></div>
                <h1>Log Out</h1>
                <p>All done? Then we guess there's nothing holding you back.</p>
            </div></a>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "the page overall loses its responsiveness too, as the cards lose their form" could you give a very detailed explanation of what that means. Start with: what is the specific difference(s) between the original page and when the page was merged with the navigation?

Comment: Well, I created 2 separate html files, one for the sidebar and the other for the rest of the content. Then I tried to merge both of them, altering some properties, and so, though I could get them positioned properly for bigger screens, when the screens get short, the cards get stretched long, and so, it means that the page is not responsive anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The simplified rule is that elements in the HTML file will be created in the order that they appear. If elements overlap, the newer element would be drawn on top of the older element.

That's the problem here. The navigation gets created, then the main contents gets created. So the main contents gets priority when those overlap.

We can change that behaviour by overwriting the order. We do that via CSS using the `z-index` property. Items with a higher z-index will be drawn over items with a lower z-index. The usual method is to set the z-index very high (e.g. 10000) so that the element with that z-index would appear above everything else.

The only change is that I've added `z-index: 10000;` to `.navbar`:

```css
:root{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    --text-primary: #b6b6b6;
    --text-secondary: #ececec;
    --bg-primary: #152238;
    --bg-secondary: #141418;
    --transition-speed: 600ms;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #bbff99;
    background-image: linear-gradient(319deg, #bbff99 0%, #ffec99 37%, #ff9999 100%);
    background-size: cover;

}

/* Used to colorize the browser scrollbar*/
body::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0.45rem;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background: #1e1e24;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #6649b8;
}

main{
    margin-left: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.todima{
    position: relative;
    top: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
}


.navbar{
    width: 4.5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
    transition: width 200ms ease;
    z-index: 10000;
}

.navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}


.logo{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.3ch;

}

.navbar-item{
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-item:last-child{
    margin-top: auto;
}

.nav-link{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 5rem;
    color: var(--text-primary);
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
    transition: var(--transition-speed);

}
.nav-link:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0%) opacity(1);
    background: #0a304a;
    
}

.link-text{
    display: none;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
}
.nav-link i{
    min-width: 2rem;
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
.navbar:hover{
    width: 16rem;
}
.navbar:hover .link-text{
    display: block;
}

.fas{
    color: #F98125;
    transition:var(--transition-speed);
}
.a1{
    font-family: 'Major Mono Display', monospace;
}


h1{
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
    margin: 7px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    font-size: 36px;
    color:#0B1354;
}

p{
    margin: 7px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
    color: #660F56;
}


.cardcont{
    background: #FFFAFA;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 40px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    perspective: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
}

.cardcont:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.cardcont:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cardcont:hover{
    border-width: 8px;
    border-style: outset;
    border-left-color: #e975a8;
    border-top-color:#e975a8 ;
    border-bottom-color: #7ddff8;
    border-right-color: #7ddff8;
    transition: 0.5s;
}


.container{
    position: relative;
    top: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card-image{
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin: 6px;
}
.image-1{
    background-image: url(dashboardprofile.png);
}

.image-2{
    background-image: url(picks.png);
}

.image-3{
    background-image: url(http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/_uploads/photos/b5f9c7fc/pexels-suzy-hazelwood-1130980_450x130.jpg);
}

.image-4{
    background-image: url(contributor.png);
}

.image-5{
    background-image: url(request.png);
}

.image-6{
    background-image: url(logout.png);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dashboard withh Cards</title>
    <!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7d904839de.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mergerdraft.css">  
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@600&family=Major+Mono+Display&family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="logo">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <span class="link-text logo-text">Cuet Course Insights</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-file-download fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Download books</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Report an issue</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-2x"></i>
                    <span class="link-text">Log Out</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <section class="todima">
            <h1 class="a1">Welcome to your dashboard</h1>
            <p>Glad to have you here. Hope you make the best use of your time. </p>
        </section>
        <section class="container">
            <a href="dashboard.html" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-1"></div>
                <h1>Profile</h1>
                <p>Visit your profile and all related information in this tab</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-2"></div>
                <h1>Your Picks</h1>
                <p>See your specially hand-picked items, without the peril of following all the steps.</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-3"></div>
                <h1>Course materials</h1>
                <p>Find and read the Books, Previous year Questions, Notes of all the toppers from our vast library of resources. In short, GO FOR GLORY!</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-4"></div>
                <h1>Be a Contributor</h1>
                <p>Wanna contribute to the community? No one ever regrets it, by helping others who might be in need. Go on!</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-5"></div>
                <h1>Request materials</h1>
                <p>Click here to reach us. Request content(question papers, books) for any course of any department and we'll hear you out. Just fill up the details.</p>
            </div></a>
            <a href="" class="cardcont"><div class="card">
                <div class="card-image image-6"></div>
                <h1>Log Out</h1>
                <p>All done? Then we guess there's nothing holding you back.</p>
            </div></a>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

---

The second question is about handling different screen sizes. The best way to do that is via [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). Those allow you to add a set of rules to your CSS file, which will only be processed if they match your condition(s).

For example, if you want to run some rules if the page width is 700px or narrower, you would do this:

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .cardcont {
    background-color: black;
  }
}
```

You can have multiple media queries and each one can have multiple conditions. Media queries are usually put at the end of the CSS file, because that allows you to overwrite earlier rules.

I would suggest that you use those to make changes to the page at small sizes. Examples changes would be:

- Removing the margin from `.cardcont`.
- Move the navigation to the top of the page.

Comment: Yup, Thanks for the z-index. Could you say , what I should do , to make the page responsive? When the screen size reduces, the cards stretch and it loses shape.

Comment: That makes sense. I've added a new section to the answer, which explains how to do that.